# How to fix TLE (Time limit exceeded) in my java code?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, compiler-errors, limit

I am trying to solve this question on leetcode and I have tried running it on pen and paper and it seems I should get my answer. But my code is showing **TLE** in **JAVA.** Can someone suggest me how to get rid of TLE and submit my solution? Why is it showing TLE?

**Question:** Check if string is transformable with substring sort operations.

**[Link](https://leetcode.com/problems/check-if-string-is-transformable-with-substring-sort-operations/)**

My code:

```
class Solution {
 
    public boolean isTransformable(String s, String t) {
        int p1 = s.length()-1;
        int p2 = t.length()-1;
        int p3 = s.length()-1;
        
        while(p1>-1){
           
            if(intAt(s,p1)==intAt(t,p2)){
                p1--;
                p2--;
            }else{
                while(intAt(s,p3)!=intAt(t,p2)){
                    p3--;
                    if(p3==0 && intAt(s,p3)!=intAt(t,p2)){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                swap(s,intAt(s,p1),intAt(s,p3));
            }
        }
        if(s.equals(t)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
       
    public int intAt(String s, int index)
    {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(index, index+1));
        return r;
    }  

     void swap(String s, int first, int second) {
        int temp = first;
        first  = second;
        second = temp;
    }  
}
```

Comment: What does "time limit exceeded" mean? Time it takes for your code to run? Time you have to solve the problem? It's not a **JAVA** error.

Comment: Pen and paper doesnt help you here - you should first get a solid understanding of java basics and run your code in a local IDE (so you may debug and unit test it). And note there may be a reason that this problem is tagged "hard", a simple brute force might not be a good strategy to solve this. (Hint: your swap() method is a do-nothing method!)

Comment: Also, all your code above the `if(s.equals(t)){` will do nothing. This check will simply compare the values _as-is_, as they are passed to the method – strings are immutable.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying too hard. You should just check if it's possible to create string t, using the numbers from string s. (Swapping is not needed).

First, check if both string have the same length.

Second, check for each number in string S if, this number is present in string t. Remove this number if present from string t.

- If by any case false comes up, you should return false.

Third, make sure string t is empty when you are done looping though s.

If no errors occurred, you should return true;

You TLE errors is probably there because you are taking too long to do the check. (not a java error).

Comment: well, i came up with the same idea - elegant, efficient... and perhaps wrong. You might want to verify your algorithm against example #3